# Are the attributes set by the "chattr" command implemented as extended attributes?

Tags: linux, xattr

The `chattr` command is used to set some attributes for a file (for example:  *append only (a)*, *immutable (i)*, etc.).

Are these attributes implemented as extended attributes, or are they their own category of attributes?

Answer (score 8):

No, those flags are set using the `FS_IOC_SETFLAGS` `ioctl()` (also known as `EXT2_IOC_SETFLAGS` for `ext*` file systems, and corresponding one for other filesystems).

In most file systems that support it, that translates to one bit map of the inode structure.

For instance, in `ext4` and several other file systems, that's the `i_flags` inode structure member (a 32 bit integer).

Some foreign (non-Linux) filesystems like Apple's HFS+ have a similar concept with equivalent flags and the `FS_IOC_SETFLAGS` ioctl does the translation there.

When using the `stat` command (which dumps the inode structure) in `debugfs` on `ext*` file systems, that's the `Flags:` number  in the output:

```
 $ sudo debugfs /dev/vda
 debugfs: stat /tmp/file
 Inode: 1835209   Type: regular    Mode:  0644   Flags: 0x80010
 [...]
```

0x80000 is `FS_EXTENT_FL` (`e` in `lsattr` output), 0x10 is `FS_IMMUTABLE_FL` (`i`).

The new `statx()` system call can also return (part of) that information (not all systems at this time (early 2019) will have a recent enough version of the GNU libc (2.28 or newer) to be able to call it easily though).

On a recent system, you can use `xfs_io`'s `statx` command as an interface to the `statx()` system call:

```
$ xfs_io -rc 'statx -r' /tmp/a
[...]
stat.attributes = 0x10
[...]
```

(here 0x10 is `STATX_ATTR_IMMUTABLE`, the `FS_EXTENT_FL` one doesn't have a corresponding `statx()` flag).

Comment: Note that the ioctl request code is named FS_IOC_SETFLAGS, not FC_IOC_SETFLAGS (I tried to just edit the answer to correct that but it appears Stack Exchange doesn't allow small corrections. Since it's only a two character change to fix both places, it's not allowed here).

Comment: Thanks Dan, fixed now.